# javascript/jQuery: validating numbers coming from .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, int

I'm validating my form, just checking if in the fields where a number should be the user has entered an string.  But as I'm getting all the field values like this:

```
var number=  $("#number").val();
```

All my variables are strings.

```
alert(typeof number);
```

shows "string" with all numeric fields values.

Any ideas on how can I validate integers??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
jQuery.isNumeric( value )
```

method for this purpose. As a result you don't need any extra parsing effort.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/354/)**

Read more about **[`$.isNumeric()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)**

#### For manual parse(if you don't use above)

```
var number = parseInt($("#number").val(), 10);
```

and for check

```
if(isNaN(number)) {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isNaN(parseInt($("#number").val()));` should do the trick! If you want to work with the number at all, this might be an easier way:

```
var value = parseInt($("#number").val());

if (isNaN(value)) {
  console.log("invalid input");
} else {
  console.log("user entered: " + value);
}
```

Comment: I put one in, but reverted back. If you try to convert for example a hex with the radix in, it pulls it out as 0, which still passes the NaN test, but is even less accurate than if it was converted accurately. This depends on whether the author wants to explicitly disallow anything but a base10 integer - if they do, the code needs a bit more revision and the radix doesn't help that much